# How to do something after GridLayout is rendered?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I am using a listView control in my Windows8 JavaScript app and I am rendering the items on the page using some code which looks like:

```
            listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout({
                groupHeaderPosition: "top",
                groupInfo: this.groupInfo,
                itemInfo: this.computeItemSize
            });
```

Now I want to do some action *after* these items are rendered on the page. Any idea where I can set a callback for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of create a renderer: declare a WinJS.Binding.Template, or create a custom render function

**WinJS.Binding.Template**

To create a WinJS.Binding.Template, you use HTML markup to define a template for how an item is rendered. Within the template, you use data binding to associate properties of the HTML elements with fields in the data record

**Custom render function**
You can define custom render function for converting a data record into its HTML representation. The advantages of implementing a custom renderer are:
It can perform customized element recycling.
It can supply placeholder elements.
It can render items progressively.
It can make incremental requests for data, if needed.

The render function takes these parameters:
object renderItem(itemPromise, recycledElement)
itemPromise: a IItemPromise for the data for the item to render. With a synchronous datasource, the IItemPromise is usually complete, but with an async datasource, it will complete at some time in the future.
recycledElement : the DOM from a previous item that can be reused to display new content.
The render function must return either:
The root element of a DOM tree for the item.
An object that contains these properties:
element: the root element of a DOM tree for the item, or a promise that when completed will return the root element for the item.
renderComplete: a Promise that completes when the item is fully rendered.
The Entire information for the link is given below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781224.aspx#displaying_items_with_a_template_or_render_function

Hope it helps...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On your listview, listen for the loadingstatechanged event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700709.aspx